# Разница между Cat c = new Cat() и Animal c = new Cat(). class Cat extends Animal

Tags: java, наследование, полиморфизм, переопределение

Друзья, привет.
Разжуйте, пожалуйста, какая разница между кодом, если класс Cat наследует (расширяет) класс Animal?

```
    Cat c = new Cat();

    Animal c = new Cat();
```

Вызовы функции `c.makeSound()` дают одинаковый вывод в консоль:  `Meow`
Нужно ли создавать объект типа Animal в таком случае?

И является ли в таком случае создание метода makeSound() в классе Cat  переопределением (overriding) этого же метода в родительском классе?
Весь код:

```
    class Animal {
public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Grr...");
      }
    }

    class Cat extends Animal {
public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("Meow");
      }
    }

    class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cat c = new Cat();
    c.makeSound();

    //Animal c = new Cat();
    //c.makeSound ();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Это уже давно все разжевано в одном километре книг и различных видео на тему Java. Если решил изучать Java, то не поленись прочитать пару троек книг по Java Core и все наладится. Особенно прочти Философия Java. Это Must have.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий

Answer (score 1):

Разница состоит в полиморфизме и динамическом связывании.

Когда вы пишите `Animal a = new Cat()`, то вы расширяете объект класса Cat до объекта его базового класса Animal (восходящее преобразование).
А суть динамического связывания состоит в том, что всегда вызывается "новая" версия метода `makeSound`. Именно поэтому при вызове `a.makeSound()` вызывается версия подкласса Cat, а не суперкласса Animal. Эта связь определяется во время выполнения программы (отсюда и название - **динамическое связывание**).

> Нужно ли создавать объект типа Animal в таком случае?

Если Вы будите создавать только объект типа Animal, то вы не сможете вызвать нужную версию метода `makeSound`, которая будет печатать *Meow*.

И да, когда вы пишите метод с такой же сигнатурой в классе-наследнике, то это и есть переопределение (override) метода базавого класса. Важно не сужать уровни доступа при определении метода, иначе нарушается полиморфизм.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я правильно понимаю, что переопределение может иметь место без анотации @Override?

Comment: @Vikrot Viktor, да. Анотация - это всего лишь методанные, без которых компилятор может запустить программу